# Dropdown in jquery repeater returns null to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a program that uses a jQuery repeater, the purpose being to be able to add multiple activities to an individual.

I have gotten this working fine except that, my dropdown list passes back null to the controller if no value is selected and i'm not sure where to pass it as a hidden field. In the event I select a value that value is passed back and saved, but if I do not edit the value, the current value doesn't persist and i'm unsure of how to pass it hidden.

I have posted the code that I could seeing how some of it is quite long so please inform if there is something else I should add.

Model.

```
public class CON_studentInfoVM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public string image { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public List<actVm> act { get; set; }
}

public class actVm
{
    public Nullable<int> id { get; set; }
    public string studentID { get; set; }
    public string textinput { get; set; }
    public string untypedinput { get; set; }

    public int checkboxinputSuper { get; set; }
    public string selectinput { get; set; }
    public string activities { get; set; }
    //Dropdown is activities
    public List<string> multipleselectinput { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

//Breakpoint here shows the dropdown as being null

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(CON_studentVM con_studentinfo )
{
}
```

Part of the view

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         <div id="tab_1_4" class="tab-pane fade"> 
                        <div class="portlet-body form">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="repeater">
                                        <div class="mt-repeater form-horizontal">
                                            <h3 class="mt-repeater-title"> </h3>

                                            <div data-repeater-list="act">
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.act)
                                                    {
                                                <div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">

                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label></label>                                                              
                                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                                @Html.DropDownList("activities", null, item.activities, new {@id="activities",@name="activities", @class = "form-control " })

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <hr />                                                         

                                                        <div class="mt-repeater-input">
                                                            <label> Study</label>
                                                            <br />

                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxinputprefes" value="1" @Html.Raw(item.checkboxinputprefes>0?"checked":"") class="form-control" />
                                                        </div>





                                                        <div class="mt-repeater-input">
                                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete="" class="btn btn-warning mt-repeater-delete">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Delete
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>



                                                </div>
                                                    }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-primary mt-repeater-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                                        </a>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: **dropdown list passes back null to the controller if no value is selected** This is the normal behavior. Why  do you want to pass a value hidden ? what value ? random value ?

Comment: @Shyju It's on the edit page, the value was already selected on create and loaded. But if i edit everything besides the value in the dropdown i'd like the current value to persist

Comment: in the edit page, you should load the selected option in the dropdown so that when user submits the form, that will be also submitted

Comment: @Shyju They are actually there in the dropdown as being selected.